# Changing WSO2 / Synapse to expose CXF service instead of AXIS2

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Currently WSO2/Synapse uses AXIS 2 services as a base and proxy service tag exposes a typical service based on AXIS 2 engine.

Is it possible to change this to expose CXF service instead? If it's not currently supported out of box, can you give an idea of how large that effort would be if I am ready to make those changes myself in WSO2/Synapse

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

`CXF` based inbound endpoint implementation will be release with the next ESB(4.9.0) version. This feature is primarily for `CXF` reliable message support. If you need to write your own custom inbound endpoint on the CXF, you can check the existing ESB 4.9.0 code base;

> https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/tree/master/components/inbound-endpoints/org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.ext.wsrm